# Left outer join a nested select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to set up a classic 'like' model for Posts on a blog, where users can create one Like for any Post. I have the following models:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  has_many :likes
end

class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true
end
```

In my controller I monitor the currently logged in user, `current_user`.

I would like to add a column to my Posts model that indicates whether or not `current_user` has liked each Post.

I tried adding a method to the Posts model that looks for likes:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes
  def user_liked
    !likes.empty?
  end
end
```

And using `includes` in the controller method.

```
@posts = Post.includes(likes: { user: current_user }).where(safe_params).order(order)
render json: @posts
```

However I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError (#<User id: 1, username: "pete", ... > was not recognized for preload):
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:51:in `index'
```

I'm using Rails API 5.0.

---

**Update:**

To clarify, I'm looking for the Rails equivalent of this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Posts
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT * 
     FROM Likes
     WHERE Likes.user_id = current_user.id) AS MyLikes
ON Posts.id = MyLikes.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `includes` takes the name of associations as parameters (like `:user, :likes, :posts`) as parameter and does not include any instances(In your case `current_user`)

You could try the following instead.

```
@posts = Post.includes(likes: :user).where(safe_params).order(order)
```

If you want to check if posts belong to current_user or not (in haml view for example)

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  - if post.likes && post.likes.any? { |like| like.user_id == current_user.id } 
    %span You have commented on this post
```

Comment: This selects all the Posts that have a Like by `current user`. I want all Posts with a column that indicates if the `current_user` liked it or not.

Comment: OK, then just drop `where(likes: { user_id: current_user.id })`. I will update the answer

Comment: If I drop `current_user` then my `user_liked` column shows `true` if any user has liked on the Post. I only want `true` if the `current_user` has liked the Post.